# Ricoh THETA360 embed autoplay rotation

Tags: embed, theta360

Is there a way to turn on autoplay for an embeded theta360 image?
I can see the autoplay feature is turned on https://theta360.com/en/gallery/ but not when embedding the image somewhere:

```
<blockquote data-width="500" data-height="375" class="ricoh-theta-spherical-image"><a href="there url here" target="_blank">Spherical Image - RICOH THETA</a></blockquote>
<script async src="https://theta360.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Also on mobile, if I long tap for a second, I see that autoplay starts, but can't see how to automatically turn it on when it loads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've noticed that how you upload from the Theta app determines whether it auto rotates or not when embedding:

"Share without specifying the orientation" = auto rotation
"Share with the current orientation" = fixed to chosen direction always

There is no variable to set it to rotate or not (that I've found).